# DS 160 Have you traveled to any countries/regions within the last five years?

Tags: visas, usa, paperwork, applications, visa-extensions

I am in US and filing for extension from Mexico so filling up DS 160. While filling the DS 160 I came across the question "Have you traveled to any countries/regions within the last five years?"

My home country is India and I came to US in 2017. I visited India 2 times between 2018 and 2019 while I was in US and I went to London in 2016.

My question is, do I need to mention India and UK or only UK for the question asked in DS 160?

Comment: I'm curious about the wording of your first sentence. You are in the US? or you are in Mexico?

Answer (score 28):

It's a fairly simple question and should not be too onerous of a task. List all the countries you've visited in the last 5 years.

You've been to the UK and India, so state that you've been to the UK and India.   Have you been to Mexico too?  If so, then state that.

Comment: OP has also been to the US.

Comment: Yep; I think that's covered in the statement "[l]ist all the countries you've visited in the last 5 years".

Comment: I heard that this answer should exclude USA and the Home country.? Please correct me